# What is this type of file AND is there a parser?

Tags: file-type

```
type: confs
targets:
 - /opt
excludes:
 - ".whicotew.phsusr"
cron_min: "5"
cron_hour: "00"
uploads:
 - rsync
```

I'm searching for its parser like `jq` for JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1508544/178692), your file appears to be YAML.

If you are already familiar with `jq` you may find the jq wrapper [kislyuk /
yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq)  (installable via pip) useful. To simply convert your file to JSON for example:

```
$ yq '.' yourfile
{
  "type": "confs",
  "targets": [
    "/opt"
  ],
  "excludes": [
    ".whicotew.phsusr"
  ],
  "cron_min": "5",
  "cron_hour": "00",
  "uploads": [
    "rsync"
  ]
}
```

or to extract a value

```
$ yq -r '.targets[0]' yourfile
/opt
```

or to add to the `targets` array and output the result as YAML

```
$ yq -y '.targets += ["/media"]' yourfile
type: confs
targets:
  - /opt
  - /media
excludes:
  - .whicotew.phsusr
cron_min: '5'
cron_hour: '00'
uploads:
  - rsync
```

Comment: It works!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a [YAML file](https://yaml.org/) - but without any context, it's difficult to give any more details.

There is a [Python YAML parser](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/yamllint) in the Universe repositories - the package name is `yamllint`.